# Why do I sometimes get _id as a string and sometimes get _id as ObjectID?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<template name="drink">
  <button class="btn btn-block{{isActive _id}}" data-drink-id="{{_id}}" data-vote-for="{{voteFor}}">{{name}}</button>
</template>
```

And my helpers/events look like this:

```
Template.drink.events({
    "click button": function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set(Session.get("activeChar"), $(event.target).data('drink-id'));
    }
  })

  Template.drink.helpers({
    isActive: function(id) {
      console.log("id: " + id);
      console.log("session: " + Session.get(Session.get("activeChar")));
      return (id == Session.get(Session.get("activeChar"))) ? " btn-positive" : "";
    },
    voteFor: function() {
      return Session.get("activeChar");
    }
  })
```

And my output looks like this:

```
id: 5668f7dc4b44184781b57abc
session: ObjectID("5668e94f4b44184781b57abb")
id: 5668e94f4b44184781b57abb
session: ObjectID("5668e94f4b44184781b57abb")
```

Why in the world do I get the string ID when I am using the helper and I get the ObjectID when I'm referencing the variable directly: `{{_id}}` ?

Comment: Generally when you concatenate strings with objects, you end up with strings. Using `+` in your console logs will coerce the value to a string, but you still have a different result, which is strange, but it seems to have something to do with how the object is stored in the session, so maybe the cursor is lost in the session ?

Comment: @adeneo The issue is more on the template side. `{{_id}}` is returning the ObjectID, but `{{isActive _id}}` pass just the string to the `id` variable. Again, when I deploy it both cases I just get the string.

Comment: I just figured out why it is different in my dev environment and when I deploy. It has to do with how I inserted the documents in my local env. (using the mongo shell vs. the console). Still not sure why the render differently in the helper vs referencing the variable though.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectID()` ones are probably docs you created via a mongo interface as opposed to within Meteor.

Comment: This explains why locally it's different than when the site was deployed (as noted in my comments above), but it doesn't explain why it renders differently on the template if it has a helper or not.